# Blanking the local terminal on boot

Tags: terminal

Could anyone help me blank the local terminal on bootup? I need the screen completely blank before a fullscreen app opens.
I've removed everything but I still have -

```
pi@raspberryPi:~$
```

I can manually remove it using

```
sudo sh -c "TERM=linux setterm -foreground black -clear all >/dev/tty0"
```

but putting this in `sudo crontab -e`, a systemctl script, or `/etc/rc.local` isn't working.

The service works if I run it manually, `sudo systemctl start black.service` so I think it's just a timing issue, can I make it wait for the user to logon?

Comment: If I recall, that prompt can be modified via an environment variable.  PS1? So `export PS1=''`

Comment: not sure where I'd put that? I tried it in terminal and nothing happened, whereas the command above works if typed in manually

Comment: I've got it work in a hacky way, but not the most elegant. Ideally would like a nicer soloution.
I've added /bin/sleep 0.1 before the commands in the sh file and just repeated all it about 50 times.

Comment: You can try putting it in ~/.bashrc

Comment: I also tried that, it didn't work

Comment: You say "but putting this in sudo crontab -e, a systemctl script, or /etc/rc.local isn't working." Try running the command in pi's session, not root's.

Comment: Well yeah as I said running the command works, but this needs to happen on every boot

Answer (score 0):

The `pi@raspberryPi:~$` is created in `.bashrc` which is called by the `.profile` file. Those two file can be changed to to do something else.